# Can termination code be implemented for Powershell module

Tags: powershell

Currently, it is possible to execute code on loading a module by simply writing the code at the script scope. However, is there a way to execute code when the module is unloaded. The only work-around is to create a Dispose- function to be called before Remove-Module.

To explain the ultimate objective, I am creating a C# enumerated type when the module loads. I would like the enumerated type to be destroyed, since it lives at the script host level, causing an error when a module is loaded and reloaded.

Comment: onRemove is called prior to removal according to [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Modules/ModuleCmdletBase.cs#L5199)

Comment: Alternatively - check for existence of the type when loading, and destroy it if if exists.